Which level of myopia is the highest possible to be allowed to drive a car?
Is there the highest corrected myopia level (in diopters) that allows you to drive a car in the US? Implying that you get 90%+ vision acuity with that correction (with glasses/lenses), but more than that you are not allowed even if the correction is perfect - due to exceeding the certain D value of the correction (as I know, in Russia it's -8D, but not sure if this applies to the situation when you drive a personal car).
P.S. I'll clarify: it might be your myopia level per se (if there is a ceiling even if you can get 100% VA using glasses/lenses), or might be the maximum optical power of the lenses in your glasses or of the contact lenses you are allowed to drive in.
PSS In Russia this -8D limitation works for truck/public transport driving.

I guess the main problem will be that with very high correction values, the viewing range will be the limiting factor.

@PMF With contact lenses on there's subjectively no change in FOV.

May well depend on the specific US state. Mine says "standards for vision are 20/40 or better in at least one eye, with or without glasses."

@JonCuster So dyoptres don't mean actually, only your acuity in glasses/lenses? I think there IS difference in glasses (not in lenses) between e.g. -2D and -9D, in -9D wide glasses there are distortions on your FOV sides.

Going by what it says, if vision can be corrected to at least 20/40 in one eye you can get a license. It says nothing about maximum diopters for uncorrected vision. (20/40 is something like -0.75 diopters).

-8 diopters corrected vision seems like way too lenient of a cutoff. When I went to join the military (decades ago), I was rejected for my uncorrected vision passing the -8 diopters limit, even though my corrected vision was 20/20. Now, granted, you might think the military had higher standards, but speaking from experience, -8 diopters is practically blind.

@BenHocking I've heard about such limitations in the military as well. One reason (which might or might not have applied in your case) was that the military glasses that one would get when entering service where using the cheapest available glass type, which results in very thick lenses for large corrections. If the glass was getting to thick this was impractical, so one was declared unfit.

FWIW, this is a question of state law in the United States. State laws are similar but not identical.

In the military, glasses may be destroyed in combat, and just stopping your activities and getting a ride home isn't an option.

"Is there the highest corrected myopia level" -- don't you mean "uncorrected" (i.e., the level of myopia before correction)? That also seems to be confusing @BenHocking.

@BenHocking No, I meant corrected - in Russia, it probably works like that (I need to delve into that) - at least on some driver categories you can't get your license even if you have your myopia corrected, but the level of correction exceeds -8D. Your myopia might be -9D, but if you still have your visual acuity in more than 60% in -8D glasses - you still can drive - your glasses/lenses can't exceed -8D. I want to figure out what happens in the US.

exceed -8D for public transport/truck driving license

@GeorgeGlebov ... That's frightening! I can't imagine someone driving who is at -8 diopters with corrected vision. Anything worse than -2.5 diopters of corrected vision (i.e., 20/200) in the US is considered legally blind. https://www.allaboutvision.com/conditions/myopia-faq/is-myopia-a-disability.htm

@BenHocking I mean if you have -8.5 myopia - you put on -8.5D glasses - you see 100% (20/20) - you can't drive public transport or truck in these glasses because you exceeded -8D correction. With your glasses ON, I meant that of course.

@GeorgeGlebov I'm not sure if we're having a language barrier or not. If my uncorrected vision is -8.5 diopters and I put on glasses to correct this, then my corrected vision is 20/20 (0 diopters), so no problems. However, if I have some sort of really, really bad vision so that even after I put on my glasses, my vision is 20/1000, then one could say my corrected vision is -8 diopters. If your corrected vision is that bad, then you shouldn't be driving. In fact, in the US, per law, if your corrected vision is -2.5 diopters, you shouldn't drive. Thus the need to distinguish between the two.

@BenHocking Sorry, it indeed might be a language barrier, I might've used it incorrectly. By using the word "corrected" I meant that you have this myopia level, and you corrected it by using glasses, but you still have this level of myopia and still have this level of correction in the lenses. So technically you see 20/20 in the glasses, but it doesn't mean that you don't have this myopia and the correction.

@BenHocking If I were to use "uncorrected myopia level" of course I would mean something in range -0.5/-1 max. Of course if you want to drive with -8/-9 - you have to have it "corrected". Otherwise it's just nonsense to drive without glasses having -9. Yep, probably my English or cultural misunderstanding.

@GeorgeGlebov, okay then that makes more sense. For usage in the US, when we say your uncorrected myopia level, we mean what your myopia level would be without corrective lenses. The military cares about this, but few others do. For general driving, however, it's the corrected myopia level they care about—how well can you see when wearing corrective lenses (contacts or glasses).

@BenHocking Yeah, so there are different stories: 1. You have uncorrected myopia -9D without glasses. 2. You have it corrected (wearing glasses). 3. In this glasses you might have still like -0.5/-1D uncorrected (remaining). When I said "corrected" I meant that it doesn't affect you (you're wearing glasses, so you see ~100%), but it technically hasn't disappeared, so you have to wear these glasses.
So, I think it would have been much easier to ask "is there the maximum level (in diopters) of myopia correction that allows you to drive". Or, really, "is there the highest uncorrected level".

I've gotten driver's licenses in two states: Ohio and California. Both rely on visual acuity, not your diopters or astigmatism values. Both say 20/40 visual acuity. If you need to wear glasses or contacts, they add a restriction to your license that you're required to wear them.
California lists a number of other issues which could cause problems while driving.
Ohio, beyond the 20/40 acuity, also lists 70 degreees of side vision in each eye.
Both states have forms that a doctor can fill out to help you get or keep a license even with some visual issues.
If I remember correctly, FOV (field of vision) in both states by flashing a light off to the side. It's not a stringent test like identify a sign or anything. It's more of a--do you notice something is there so you can move your eyes or turn your head to identify it.
Personal anecdote: My current prescription is between -9.5 up to -11. I also have an issue that my right eye doesn't move much to the right beyond 'straight ahead'  due to a congenital (born with) nerve problem (Duane's syndrome). Neither issue has hindered my being able to get a driver's license. Now that I'm starting to get presbyopia, I have 'distance/driving' glasses and 'computer/near' glasses. Optometrists and ophthmalogists can adjust prescriptions for different ranges if you need them.
I was never able to adjust to bifocals. For me, using bifocals with large computer screens requires tipping my head back which was not comfortable for long.

I'm about a -7 in both eyes and have progressive lenses that don't require much head tilt.

@JonCuster I suspect that you're using smaller lenses than I am. Mine are about 0.75" from pupil to bottom of lens. (and about 1.25" total top to bottom)

It’s not based on diopters
australia
There are a number of factors and they differ between private and commercial licences. The hard and fast limits apply to the granting of an unconditional licence, the authority may grant a conditional licence even if you don’t meet the parameters on the advice of your optometrist or ophthalmologist.
In summary for a private licence you need better than:

uncorrected acuity of 6/12 (or 20/40 for those still using imperial measures) in the better eye or both eyes together. A conditional licence will be issued if you can meet this with correction.
a horizontal extent of 110 degrees
no significant loss within the central 20 degrees
additional rules apply if you are monocula or have diplopia.


"uncorrected acuity of 6/12 (or 20/40 for those still using imperial measures)" <-- It never occurred to me until just now that 20/20 refers to imperial measures, though of course it does. While I'm generally pro-metric (even though I live in the US), I don't think I could get used to saying "hindsight is 6/6" instead of "hindsight is 20/20", for example.

@BenHocking in Russian everyone uses % when talking about VA, or just straight "one" when 100%. I think 6/12 means 50% VA.

@GeorgeGlebov no it doesn’t, it means that what a person at the lower end of “normal” vision (I.e. standardised Snelen 6/6 or 20/20 vision) can read at 12m (20 feet), a person with 6/20 needs to be at 6m (20 feet). It will not correspond to 50% because they are clearly different methodologies.

@DaleM Yeah, 6/30 is not 0.5
it corresponds to 0.3 (30%), 20/20 or 6/6 is 100% (1.0), 20/200 is 0.1 (10%), 6/12 I'm sure corresponds to 0.5 or 50%.
